# Problems Adding Second ResourceDictionary in CustomControl Library WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, dictionary

I am building a project in vs2010 which will eventually be a template for a number of small projects I have to write.
I have successfully extended extended a TextBox control and added it to a CustomControl Library and  created a Resource Dictionary for it's default style and merged this into my main project will Generic.xaml and it works.

The problem comes when I try to extend the idea and create a new Resource Dictionary for a label to be used for settings. When I try and reference the Style in my mainwindow xaml it throws the following

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
>     Message='Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '68' and line position '48'.
>      InnerException: 
>          Message=Cannot find resource named 'Settings'. Resource names are case sensitive.
>          Source=PresentationFramework

So I can see the error but am not sure why I get it. If I move the Style to a Window Resource all is fine.

Please could someone explain what I am missing please is it a namespace or something?

My Resource Dictionary xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CHCustomControlLibrary1">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="Settings">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="90" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />

</Style>
```

My Generic file located in Themes

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CHCustomControlLibrary1">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/CHCustomControlLibrary1;component/ResourceDictionaries/ExTextBoxDictionary.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/CHCustomControlLibrary1;component/ResourceDictionaries/SettingLabelsDictionary.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}" />
```

My main window xaml which throws the error

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                                           Content="Property1" 
                                           Name="lbProp1"                                                
                                           Style="{StaticResource Settings}"/>
```

My full main window xaml

> 

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalExpander" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Border Name="ContentBorder"
            Width="0">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded"
                 Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder"
                    Property="Width"
                    Value="Auto" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
        <!--<Button Name="B1" Content="T" Click="B1_Click"/>-->
        <Button Name="B2"
            Click="B2_Click" Height="28" >
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="Icons\tool.ico" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <Expander Name="MainExpander2"
                  Template="{StaticResource VerticalExpander}"
                  IsExpanded="False"
                  DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                <Border Background="Gray" Width="250" >
                    <StackPanel Height="348" Name="stackPanel1" Width="250" >
                        <Label Content="Settings:" Height="28" Name="label1" />
                        <ScrollViewer Height="275" Name="scrollViewer1" Width="238">
                            <StackPanel Height="320" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-3,-4,0,0" Name="stackPanel2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="203" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                <Grid Height="318" Name="grid1" Width="197">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="30*" />


                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                   <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                                           Content="Property1" 
                                           Name="lbProp1"                                                
                                           Style="{StaticResource Settings}"/>
                                    <MyNamespace:ExTextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                                                            Name="tbProp1" />
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Expander>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel>
        <Border Name="NonSliding"
            Width="100"
            Height="50"
            Background="Green">

        </Border>

            <Button Content="Test" Height="23" Name="btTestSave" Width="75" Click="btTestSave_Click" />
            <Button Content="Test Save" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="75" />
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Height="31" Name="border1" Width="132">
                <TextBox Height="23" Name="tbTestSave" Width="120" />
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: You need to check the paths of merged dictionaries whether those are correct or not.

Comment: Hi @Nikita, thank you for your comment. I have double check those and cut and pasted the names from file explorer! I get no errors when I rebuild the project, which I do normally get if my paths are wrong

Comment: Can you check this - merge the resource dictionary to App.Xaml instead of generic.xaml.

Comment: Ok - yes that works - thank you, but why and I thought you where meant to use Generic?

Comment: I will also check that.this trial was only to check whether the resource dictionaries works fine.

Comment: I try merging Generic.xaml to App.xaml & it worked. but as you said that should not be needed. still I need to check